# Webservices - change default template for new Site

Tags: web-services, liferay, sitetemplate

Through Webservices creating Site (GroupService) for organization. This site is generated implicitly with a blank template (Blank Site).

I need to set a different default template when generating a new Site.

Or is something else via Webservices to assign a template to Site?

I use Liferay 6.1.

Thanks